# How to set the loader locale?

Tags: dojo, locale, loader, intern

When I run my application in the browser, I can specify `locale: 'en'` as part of `dojoConfig`. When I run the tests in Node.js, the locale setting is the default value `en`. When I run the tests in a browser, the locale setting is set with the top preferred language of the browser (which is French in my case)...

I tried without success to set `locale: 'en'` as part of the `loader` configuration in my Intern config file:

```
return {
    useLoader: { 'host-browser': 'node_modules/dojo/dojo.js' },
    loader: {
        locale: 'en',
        packages: [{
            name: 'dojo',
            location: 'src/libs/dojo'
        }, {
        ...
    }
};
```

How can I set the `locale` setting for my tests running into the browsers? As I've two Intern config files, I don't mind doing something different for Node.js and for the browsers.

A+, Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just hit the same issue (because `dojo/_base/config.js` was blowing up due to `navigator.language` being empty and `navigator.userLanguage` being `undefined` in my Firefox installation), and needed to get a locale set.

I ended up resorting to adding this to my `testconfig.js`:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // We're running inside a browser.
    window.dojoConfig = window.dojoConfig || {};
    window.dojoConfig.locale = window.dojoConfig.locale || "en-us";
}
```

Not sure whether that's 'the correct' way to do it, but it seems to be working for me with Intern 2.1.1.